# How can I group my applications in start menu deployed by clickOnce?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, startmenu

I have created a set of applications which are deployed using clickonce. is it possible to group them in a common start menu item?

Background : I have created a series of [quantitative finance related calculators](http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/) in my website, which are deployed using ClickOnce. All apps are related, and it will be easier to locate them if they are under a common menu item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the Publisher Name to the same for all your application, and they'll all appear in a subfolder on the start menu. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shfsy39d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the description on how to do that in Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

Also if you are using .NET 3.5 or above, you can fill in the Suite Name field in the Options dialog and it will also group by that.